# Appending two dataframes with multindex rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

The first one looks like this:

|  |  | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| entry | subentry |  |
| 0 | 1 | X |
|  | 2 | Y |
|  | 3 | Z |

and the second one looks like:

|  |  | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| entry | subentry |  |
| 0 | 1 | A |
|  | 2 | B |

I would like to merge the two dataframe such that I get:

|  |  | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| entry | subentry |  |
| 0 | 1 | X |
|  | 2 | Y |
|  | 3 | Z |
| 1 | 1 | A |
|  | 2 | B |

Simply using `df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)` gives

|  | variable |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| 0 | X |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | Z |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | B |

In other words, it collapses the multindex into a single index. Is there a way around this?

Edit: Here is a code sinppet that will reproduce the problem:

```
    arrays = [
        np.array([0,0,0]),
        np.array([0,1,2]),]
    arrays_2 = [
        np.array([0,0]),
        np.array([0,1]),]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 1), index=arrays)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 1), index=arrays_2)
    df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

Edit: In practice, I am looking ao combine N dataframes, each with a different number of "entry" rows. So I am looking for an approach that will not rely on me knowing the exact  of the dataframes I am combining.

Comment: Ah, thank you @not_speshal I missed it.

Comment: I have added a code snippet that would re-produce the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way try:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[0,1]).droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
            0
0 0 -0.439749
  1 -0.478744
  2  0.719870
1 0 -1.055648
  1 -2.007242
```

Use pd.concat to concat the dataframes together and since entry is the same of both, use keys parameter to create a new level with the naming you want your level to be.  Finally, go back and drop the old index level (where the value was the same).

Comment: Hi, thaks for the answer! How would this approach generalise if i don't know that I have just two entries at the first level? my use case will involve concatinating a long list of dataframes, all with different lengths. I will edit the question to note that :)